# Can't read a list of shp file in R

Tags: r, r-sf

I tried to open a list of shp file, using this code:

```
path_par <- list.files(path = "E:\\core", full.names = T, pattern = "shp")
parch <-path_par %>% map(read_sf)
```

But I receive this error message:

```
Error: Cannot open "E:\core\CorePO_Esc0.shp.xml"; The source could be corrupt or not supported. See `st_drivers()` for a list of supported formats.
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not an expert on this, but I thought that `read_sf` was intended to read `.shp` files, not `.xml` files. Do you mean `pattern="\\.shp$"` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `$`in your pattern (if not your are trying to open one of the many [sidecars files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile)) :

```
dir.create("test")
file.create("test/my_file.shp")
file.create("test/my_file.shp.xml")
list.files("test")

path_par <- list.files(path = "test", full.names = T, pattern = "shp$")
path_par
```